# Rep increase from "removed" thing that wasn't removed

Tags: support

I just dropped by my reputation activity page and saw this:

[image: Picture of rep list with +1 next to "removed" item]

The thing is, I hadn't removed my downvote from the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540857/remove-html-tag-using-jquery/13540915#13540915) (the "Remove HTML tag using jQuery" one it takes me to when I click through) or indeed done anything at all two minutes earlier, nor had the related answer been deleted. Why did I suddenly get +1 rep?

Having captured the above, I then did a rep recalc, and it disappeared. Gremlins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post was deleted and then undeleted.  This would explain what happened.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13540915/revisions

Comment: *Sigh* I should have looked at that. Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, without any "real" edit one has to manually post the URL of the post revisions page which is a pain. :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Unfortunately when things get *undeleted*, no new event gets added to the reputation history, but it still re-adjusts your reputation and doesn't remove the deletion event from the history. *Confusion.*

Answer (score 2):

According to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13540915/revisions), the poster deleted the post and then undeleted it 2 minutes later.